# Fedora 32 System Settings Missing

Tags: fedora, nvidia, settings

In the process of installing the nvidia proprietary driver on my Fedora 32 machine, somehow the system settings application has lost its menu bar on the left.  All I have are a few "common" items to choose from.  Can anyone tell me how I might go about recovering this?  I did not remove any KDE applications.  This seems to have happened while I was getting the displays configured.  Here is a screen capture of the system settings application.  Anyone?
Thanks in advance,
Dave

[image]

Comment: I tried adding the KDE Environment again through dnf, but it did not resolve the issue.  The command was "dnf group install kde-desktop-environment".